# I dont have fragment.xml when i create a new project

Tags: android

I installed the latest eclipse and android ADT. so while following android.developers site they say I have to start creating a fragment.xml however I only have main_acticity. what should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

its a bug, you will have to create them manually. or simply follow this steps.

I've found a patch. You can change the file:

$SDK_TOOLS/tools/templates/activities/BlankActivity/recipe.xml.ftl

The forth line:

<#if appCompat>

must be changed to:

<#if appCompat?has_content> ....

adding the "?has_content". The same must be done in

$SDK_TOOLS/tools/templates/activities/BlankActivity/root/res/menu/main.xml.ftl

at the end of the first line:

should also be added:

...<#if appCompat?has_content>

This seems to solve the issue. This problem also exists when creating many other activities.

This is so annoying...

[Source of soulution](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72571)

Comment: srry for this stupid question but where I should find the file $sdk_tools.... ?   and what other activities .. I am trying to learn how to develop a mobile and such bugs making that harder @k0sh

Answer (score 0):

Select Empty Activity while creating a new project or update to build tools 20 which gives a separate choice of black activity without fragments.

This is not a bug. Learn more about it here - [Android Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)